create a list of occurences in excel
I'm using excel and in the column I have the following items:
banana
apple
banana
apple
orange
orange
banana

They are all fruits and vegetables, but the names are unknown. I want to display the occurrence of each name so in this example it would be
banana=3, apple=2, orange=2
How do I do that on excel?
=COUNTIF(A1:A7, "banana")

I know if I try this I can find banana=3
but I want the script to identify what name of vegetable/fruit is in the list.

how about a pivot table with count?

One option is to use pivot table. Another is to use COUNTIFS() function. Try-
=HSTACK(UNIQUE(A2:A8),COUNTIFS(A2:A8,UNIQUE(A2:A8)))



One of the answers already contains the Unique() function, but I would like to present you the combination of that function, combined with your proposal, using CountIf():

As you can see, row "1" contains the titles, which is (except for the first column) the text of the formula, used for calculating the contents of that column.
So, first (column "B"), the Unique() function gets all unique entries, second (column "C") the CountIf() counts all occurrences, then both the entries and their occurrence get added (column "D") and finally (column "E"), using the TextJoin() function, everything gets summarised into one string.

Here is what I would do, using less verbose way :


=GROUPBY(Fruits,Fruits,ROWS,,0)


Or a similar one like already proposed but using UNIQUE() later and not twice:
=LET(_List, Fruits, UNIQUE(HSTACK(_List,COUNTIFS(_List,_List))))


NOTES:

GROUPBY() function is applicable to MS365 Office Insiders for now, sooner its going to be available to regular users.
Also, I am using Structured References aka Tables instead of whole range or absolute ranges, and the reason behind, it is tables are adjustable with sizes if and when new data is added or removed, the formulas will be adjusted automatically.
In the second method used LET() function makes easier to read, avoids redundancy of ranges/functions etc. improves performances as well.
Last but not least, named the Table as Fruits change as per your suit.
Note that one can use Pivot Tables but that won't update automatically like formulas unless you are refreshing the table every time some datas are added.



If an Excel Table contain only one column you don't need to repeat Table name and column name. Instead of Fruits[Fruits] it is enough to use Fruits (Table name).

Yes, I wrote Fruits only don't how it took the references. Fixed @MGonet =)
